# Where should I put my cronjobs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a special place for cronjobs in rails? I couldn't find information on this subject, the only examples out there are to execute Model.some_method

I created a class Crawler, with a method run, and tried different places for it (including app/models), but I keep getting this error:

> $ rails runner -e development 'Crawler.run'
>
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53: undefined method `run' for Crawler:Class (NoMethodError)
>
> ```
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `eval'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:53
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
> from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:64
> from script/rails:6:in `require'
> from script/rails:6
> ```

```
class Crawler
  def run
    puts 'bla'
  end
end
```

As you can see, it can't find the method 'run'.

If I put it inside /scripts I get this: uninitialized constant Crawler (NameError), so this is probably not what I want.

Any ideas?

note. I'm on rails 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling an instance method on class level.

Rewrite like this:

```
class Crawler
  def self.run
    puts 'bla'
  end
end
```

To answer your initial question, there is no real dedicated place but I usually create a `crons` folder under `app`.

Regarding rake tasks, they are supposed to live in `/lib` but it's really up to you.

Answer (score 3):

I encourage you to use the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). It allows you to set up tasks in a `schedule.rb` file as follows:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"       
  rake "my:rake:task"                 
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

Comment: I highly discourage this, unless you run on a machine with only one version of ruby and one global gemset.  Anything more than that (rvm, rbenv, etc), and plan to spend 6 to 12 hours trying to get your first simple task to run.  Then, push to your production machine and start all over.  Wherever is awful.